# T-SQL procedure call using OPENROWSET

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, export-to-csv, openrowset

I have two queries.

This first query creates a `.csv` file in a `C:\...` folder with no errors:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text;Database=C:\Temp\TEMP_SQL_FOLDER\T-SQL to csv\;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited','SELECT * FROM [test3.csv]') 
    SELECT Id, PatientNumber, Title_Id, FirstName, LastName, Gender_Id 
    FROM PPM2..Activity_Patient ap
```

This second query is supposed to do the same thing, except the `SELECT` statement is replaced with a procedure call:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text;Database=C:\Temp\TEMP_SQL_FOLDER\T-SQL to csv\;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited','SELECT * FROM [test3.csv]') 
    EXEC dbo.PPMLoad_MediRecOSRServices @FinancialYear='2020'
```

The second statement does not work and throws this error:

> Msg 7390, Level 16, State 2, Line 10
>   The requested operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" does not support the required transaction interface.

I have the necessary settings enabled:

```
USE [master]
GO 

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
GO 

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 
GO
```

The second query simply doesn't run. I'm not using any linked servers either. This is just a simple export to a local C: drive.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The implication from the error message is that SQL Server is attempting to start a distributed transaction, which the Access driver does not support.

You could try permitting non-transacted updates for the driver:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'NonTransactedUpdates', 1
```

I found this in [an answer on dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/225062/4108) - which also repeats the following warning from the ACE driver documentation, which you should probably beware of in this situation:

> The Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable is not intended: . . . To be used by a system service or server-side program where the code will run under a system account, or will deal with multiple users identities concurrently, or is highly reentrant and expects stateless behavior. Examples would include a program that is run from task scheduler when no user is logged in, or a program called from server-side web application such as ASP.NET, or a distributed component running under COM+ services.